# Class that inherits QMovie and QPixmap functions

Tags: qt, class, inheritance, qpixmap

Is there any Qt Class that Inherits everything from QMovie and QPixmap?

Comment: Why not make a subclass?

Comment: Ops, missed i can do that. :) Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Don't subclass if you don't need to

I don't think you need to...take a look at the documentation.  The `QMovie::currentPixmap` method returns a `QPixmap` of the current frame.  Can you explain what you need beyond that?

### Sources

- http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.7/qmovie.html
- http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.7/qmovie.html#currentPixmap